# ECS con Secret Manager para usar variables de entorno

Tags: aws

Necesito insertar los *secretos* de un **secret manager** dentro de un task definition de **ECS**. Me gustaría que compartieran una solución en terraform o una pequeña explicación de como se haría desde la consola de AWS o en terraform.

Este es el código para crear mi secret manager en terraform.

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "my_secret" {
  name = "ecs-auth-secret"
  description = ""
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "my_secret_version" {
  secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.my_secret.id
  secret_string = jsonencode({
    "DB_DIALECT"            : "postgres",
  })
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_policy" "secret_access_policy" {
  secret_arn = aws_secretsmanager_secret.my_secret.arn

  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "AllowAccessToSecret",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "AWS": "arn:myrole"
        }
        "Action": [
          "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
          "secretsmanager:ListSecrets"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

Estoy intentado de enlazar las variables de entorno de un contenedor de **ECS** con un **secret manager**.